# What's the structure member 'pm' in the driver structure?

Tags: linux, structure, device-driver, spi

What's 'pm' and 'of_match_table' in the following spi driver code

```
static struct platform_driver omap2_mcspi_driver = {
         .driver = {
                 .name =         "omap2_mcspi",
                 .owner =        THIS_MODULE,
                 .pm =           &omap2_mcspi_pm_ops,
                 .of_match_table = omap_mcspi_of_match,
         },
         .probe =        omap2_mcspi_probe,
         .remove =       omap2_mcspi_remove,
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look on [From where platform device gets it name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244847/from-where-platform-device-gets-it-name). You can find more details on [ACPI based device enumeration](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/acpi/enumeration.txt).